# How do I get and clean up a value in a JSON variable with only grep?

Tags: json, bash, grep

I have a variable with an example JSON format, a mix of array and objects. I am trying to get the value for one of the objects in an array, without `" or ,`

Using only the basic grep command, for read-only servers. Please note that the server has only bash, doesn't have X code, and has no way to install jq or homebrew.

```
usage: grep [-abcdDEFGHhIiJLlMmnOopqRSsUVvwXxZz] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
        [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
        [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
        [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

```
echo $exampleJSON

Output:
{
  "array": [
    {
       "ex1": 901,
       "ex2": 902,
       "ex3": 903,
       "ex4": 904,
       "ex5": 905,
       "ex6": 906,
    }
  ]
  "something_else": {
    "a1": 0
  }
}
```

The closest I have gotten is with `echo $exampleJSON | grep -Eo '"ex3":.*?[^\\],"'` which will output:

```
"ex3": 903,"
```

How can I clean up and extract `903`, assuming the value can change, please advise!

Comment: Don't. It's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Does your server _really_ not have Python installed? That's very rare these days.

Comment: (You want `ex1` only when it exists in `array`, right? So if a new version of the file had `"extra_stuff": {"ex3": "something else here"}` you'd want to avoid that, right? That kind of contextual awareness isn't something regular expressions are suited for; they only parse [regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), and [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language)).

Comment: Please post valid JSON.

Comment: The server doesn't have Python. What should I use if this particular server hasn't been worked on, and only contains the basic bash language?

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release